# Why are the labels not showing when I load a .qml file in a standalone pyqgis script?

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer

[image: IMG]
[image]

The first image is the final output that I have when I run my standalone script. The second Image shows the grid that I made and the sample labels that I want to put on my final output. I saved the style in .qml format but the only style that the script outputs is the color and transparency. not the label.

What am I missing?
I am using **QGIS 2.18** and **Ubuntu 16.04**

The code below is what I use in loading .qml files

```
uri = '/home/francis/Documents/mapfile/SHP/Grid.qml'
grdLayer.loadNamedStyle(uri)
grdLayer.triggerRepaint()
```